# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

I'm developing an asp.net a data and I would insert a data in one column. but he send it in the another line what I can do to correct this problem? it send me: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

> Error
>
> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> SQL state: 21000

```
UPDATE accident_ma
  SET geom_acc = (
    SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point (route.geom, ( 
      select (pk_accident)/(pk_fin-pk_debut)
      from route, accident_ma 
      where route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route
      order by route.num_route limit 1))
    from route, accident_ma 
    where route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route
    order by route.num_route)
  from route
  where route.gid = accident_ma.gid;
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. Did you read the actual words of the error? Your nested SELECT (the `select (pk_accident)`, if I'm reading correctly) is returning more than one row, and you can't assign that result (multiple rows) to a single column, which is what your UPDATE is trying to do.

Comment: yes but i don't khnow how i should do to send value and value ......... to geom_acc can you help me ? please

Comment: no SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point return more than row!!!

Comment: You haven't posted any sample data or the results you'd like to get from that data after the UPDATE. You've posted an UPDATE statement and a clearly stated error message. Run your SELECT by itself, figure out why it's returning multiple rows, and figure out what you need to add to the WHERE clause to reduce it to a single row that you can use. One of them is returning more than one row. The database isn't making it up. Remove the UPDATE portion  and execute the SELECTs by themselves and figure out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: yes it send me two rows SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point

Comment: You probably have route `LINESTRING`s  with multiple accidents.

Comment: no patrick the probleme int_interpolate_point had two values and geom_acc it can't save the tow values i think

Comment: If SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point is returning two rows, you've found the problem. You're absolutely right; just like I told you in my first comment, `geom_acc` cannot accept more than one row in the assignment.  Now fix it so that you narrow the scope of the select to return a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are complicating matters tremendously. Even with multiple events from `accident_ma` on a single `route.geom` the below should work just fine:

```
UPDATE accident_ma a
  SET geom_acc = ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(r.geom, a.pk_accident / (a.pk_fin-a.pk_debut))
  FROM route r
  WHERE a.num_route = r.num_route
    AND a.gid = r.gid;
```

In your code the correlated sub-query would return multiple rows when there are multiple accidents on a single route. In this solution that won't happen: every `UPDATE` operates on a single accident.

Comment: it say me ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 6:   FROM route r
          ^

Comment: i don't understand it can't works with route r!! help me pleace patrick

Comment: I can't help you if you don't tell me what's wrong. I added a table alias, see updated answer.

Comment: ok, this is the error ERROR:  column reference "num_route" is ambiguous
LINE 6:   WHERE num_route = r.num_route
                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column reference "num_route" is ambiguous
SQL state: 42702
Character: 356

Comment: You should look at the updated answer. I already added an alias to the table name